# Entities, Views, or inline SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq, asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4

I am researching the feasability of converting an existing asp.net web forms project to MVC 2 web apps project.  The existing SQL queries are of form:

```
Select [data]
from [table]
inner join [linkedDb1.Table] on key
where [constraints]
```

There are two linked DB's.  Entitity framework 4 does not support linked servers.  So I must choose:

**A**.  Create views for each table and join on the views.
**B**.  Keep the inline SQL and somehow write a custom model as a wrapper that can be consumed by Strongly Typed - partial views on the Dashboard.
**C**.  Wrap each DB in a CRUD service and join in memory (data is assumed < 100 rows by 10 columns).

**A** appears straight forward, **B** I don't know how to do, **C** is architecturally clean, but potentially performance hindered.

How do I create a custom model that works with **B**?  Does anyone foresee any project killing ideas with **A**, **B**, or **C**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a stored procedure and add that to your dbml.  It will be faster and will provide the EF objects you're looking for.

Comment: +1 Agreed. You also decouple the specifics of the problem (i.e. that at the moment the dbs are separate) from the function.

Comment: +1 - Tested and this is exactly what I need.  Thanks Sean, saved me days of going the wrong direction.